# I can only connect to my Minecraft server on my own wifi

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hosting, minecraft-spigot

I made a Minecraft server recently using spigot. It works perfect when I connect to it from the wifi that I am hosting it from, but when I try to connect from other wifi's it won't work. I connect through a domain name that I created using noip.com.

Comment: Probably you need to do port forwarding. Creating a No-IP address only solve the dynamic IP problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do something called **port forwarding**. In essence, port forwarding is mapping one IP address and port to another. Most commonly, one maps an external IP and port (that can be accessed by everyone) into an internal IP and port (which cannot), thus allowed the internal IP and port to be accessible from the outside.

---

In your case, you need to map your internal IP and port (your computer hosting your server) into an external IP and port (so everyone can visit it). I'm not going to explain how to port forward here; it is fairly complicated. But, I will provide you with some links:

- [Not specifically port forwarding, but helpful advice form `noip.com`](http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/how-to-host-and-configure-a-minecraft-server-with-no-ip/)
- [`portforward.com`](http://portforward.com/)
- [`portforward.com` specifically for Minecraft servers](http://portforward.com/softwareguides/minecraft/portforward-minecraft.htm)
- [Googling "port forwarding minecraft"; lots of useful sites](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=port%20forwarding%20minecraft)